# Is there an equivalent to MovingMap[] for functions that work on more than one TimeSeries?

Tags: map, time-series

I have a family of functions that require two TimeSeries (A and B). As a trivial example, imagine a function called beta[tsA_,tsB_] that determines the slope of the linear regression line for the changes in TimeSeries A relative to changes in TimeSeries B. It is easy to apply such a function to the entire series, but what if I want to apply it on a rolling basis?

MovingMap[] is no help because it allows only one TimeSeries as an argument. MapThread[] works but requires sacrificing all of MovingMap[]'s sophistication about TimeSeries.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a time series with multiple values and apply an arbitrary function.

```
dates = DateRange[{2015, 10, 1}, DatePlus[{2015, 10, 1}, 29]];
data = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {Length[dates], 2}];
tsdata = TimeSeries[data, {dates}];
```

Now, you can apply MovingMap on the function of your choice:

```
rollstd = MovingMap[StandardDeviation, tsdata, Quantity[4, "Days"]]
DateListPlot[rollstd, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Further, you can define a function `betafun` as Covariance[series1,series2]/Variance[series2] and use this function on the time series.

```
betafun = N[Apply[Covariance, Transpose[#]]/Last[MapAt[Variance, Transpose[#], 2]]] &;
rollbeta = MovingMap[betafun, tsdata, Quantity[4, "Days"]];
DateListPlot[rollbeta]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question!

The short answer is that there doesn't seem to be any built-in that could perform the required task, something which is already alluded to in the question,

There is, however, a way to use `MovingMap` on any number of series in a way reminiscent of using `MapThread` on ordinary expressions.

The idea is to first bundle the series in a single `TemporalObject` with appropriate `ValueDimensions` and then feed it to `MovingMap`.

Such a solution has the downside that one needs to pick the series apart and put them back together again. It could also be argued that if it comes down to extracting `"Paths"` and/or `"Values"` from the series, one can simply then use `ListConvolve` or probably `Partition` to get the job done without having to reconstruct a new `TimeSeries` in order to feed it to `MovingMap`.

Even though this doesn't sound altogether unreasonable, it wouldn't seem completely useless to attempt a solution along the lines of 'solving a `TimeSeries` problem using `TimeSeries`', even in a somewhat roundabout way:

```
(* one series, two paths *)
bundle = TemporalData[{tsA, tsB}, ResamplingMethod -> None]; 

(* resample using avail t-val pairs *)
union = TimeSeriesResample[bundle, "Union"]

(* take the 'ResamplingMethod' value with a grain of salt *)
tsopts = {ResamplingMethod -> {None, None}, ValueDimensions -> 2,
  MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}};

(* one series, vector-valued single path *)
tsx = TimeSeries[Transpose[union["Values", All]], {union["Times"]},
  Apply[Sequence][tsopts]]
```

finally,

```
MovingMap[f[Differences[#]] &, tsx, Quantity[30, "Events"]]
```

should do the trick. Obviously, `Quantity[30, "Events"]` can be replaced with any other desirable `wspec` and `f` is used as a stand-in for an appropriate fitting function; probably `Differences` is something that can be incorporated later into `f`, too.

Comment: Do you find that you can use this in real-life /production code? imho `TimeSeriesResample` is very slow

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability If I have to be completely honest, I don't think I have ever managed to write really fast Mathematica code; however, "real-life" or "production code" varies with the user; also, as far as I'm concerned, I prefer having code I know is correct even if it is somewhat slow, whatever 'slow' means; now, if we have to be specific about the particular code in the answer, I would be interested to know the dimensions of the problem instances you have encountered speed or performance issues with